# Cannot add links to global navigation on a site created from a custom web template in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: site-template, web-template

I have created a webtemplate that I use to provision a sitecollection site which works fine but when I try to add an Heading or link to the Global Navigation through UI it's not working correctly: somehow the links gets removed from the Global Navigation.

Does anyone ever experienced this behavior? What could I have done wrong? is this a know issue/bug?

Comment: Did you create the site template through code or just reused an existing site template ?

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem so I am leaving here the solution that worked for me. In the onet.xml file there is line

```
<NavBars></NavBars>
```

I have replaced it with the following one

```
<NavBars>
    <NavBar Name="SharePoint Top Navbar" ID="1002"></NavBar>
</NavBars>
```

Now its working.

Comment: Ronak, please mark this as your answer to put the question in a closed state